# Fastest way to check if a list pattern is present in another list of varying lengths?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list of lists of varying lengths.

```
list1 = [['0', '0'],['0', '1', '0', ' '],['0', '1', ' ', '0', '1', ' '],['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0'],[]]
```

I want to compare this list against another list of lists:

```
list2=[['0','0','0','0'],['1','1','1','1']]
```

Now, I want to check if list2 is contained in list1. The output should be True since list1 has `['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0']` which contains `['1','1','1','1']`

What would be the best way to check if any of the list2 elements are present in list1? The answer should be a Boolean in case any of the list2 elements are found in list1 by maintaining order. 
I have tried quite a few things, but can't seem to get the desired output. Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: `['0','0','0','0']` is not in `list1`. Do you only want to check if any available?

Comment: Yes I want to check if any available. @Austin

Comment: Do you want to ignore space string, ' '? I mean the third value in ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0'] should be ignored?

Comment: Yes spaces can be ignored. Just need to return a boolean if there's a match. @GilseungAhn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
list1  = [['0', '0'], ['0', '1', '0', ' '], ['0', '1', ' ', '0', '1', ' '], ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0'], []]
list2 = [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '1', '1']]
for i in list2:
    string2 = ''.join(i)
    for j in list1:    
         string1 = ''.join(j).replace(' ','')
         if string2 in string1:
                 print('yes',i,j)

# output yes ['1', '1', '1', '1'] ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0']
```

Comment: you could move string2 out of the inner loop, its constant so does not need to be recomputed for each j you join the shorter strings len(list1)*len(list2) times - precomputing the shorter versions is better imho

Answer (score 2):

Simplistic approach:

```
list1 = [['0', '0'],['0', '1', '0', ' '],['0', '1', ' ', '0', '1', ' '],
         ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0'],[]]
list2 = [['0','0','0','0'],['1','1','1','1']]

# computing the shortened strings once, storing as string,orignal - tuples
texts = [(''.join(inner).replace(" ",""),inner) for inner in list1]
find =  [(''.join(inner).replace(" ",""),inner) for inner in list2]

for (shortened,inner) in texts:
    for (pattern,f) in find:
        if pattern in shortened:
            print("Found", f , "in", inner)
```

to get

```
Found ['1', '1', '1', '1'] in ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '0']
```

It is simplistic because it is a quadratic search.